# Can't get the Facebook comment moderation to work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have implemented the Facebook comments plugin to a page on my site. In addition to this I would like to be bale to moderate the comments. I followed the instructions on the Facebook developer section and implemented as described. I wanted to use the inline moderation tool rather than create an app. So I placed the following meta data.

```
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="533551342"/>
```

Where the content is set to my Facebook profile ID.
I have then placed the script code as per Facebook developer instructions.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=672941899483225&version=v2.3";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
```

Once that is in place, I added the comments section to the site using the code instructed.

```
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.microspot.com/case-studies/boat_design.htm" data-width="540" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

So with all this in place the comments section shows and works, but the moderate link does not appear next to the number of posts text (which is what should happen according to face books documentation).

The web page is http://www.microspot.com/case-studies/boat_design.htm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you solved? same problem here

Comment: I did solve it and have posted the answer. : )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the issue was not with the code but with Facebook re-indexing my changes. There is a tool on the Facebook developer page for debugging and indexing your changes.

Any update you make to the Facebook code on your webpage, especially the meta data, you should always use the following debug tool.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Simply paste your webpage link (should be a live page not local) into the box and follow the instructions each time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=672941899483225&version=v2.3";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is the same code as I already have. In case I missed something, I used your snippet but the moderation link still did not appear.